# Html Email Not Aligning Correctly In Thunderbird Only

Tags: html, css, email, html-email, thunderbird

I am creating an html calendar(cal.ics) invite and it works in email clients like Gmail, Firefox, and YahooMail. But when I try it in thunderbird, the paragraph(p) tags are always off to the right, even though I've explicity set attributes like align left, float: none, etc. Am I doing something wrong? The email is below, is there something missing in my css?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Follow-Up! Meeting</title>
        <style>
            /* -------------------------------------
             GLOBAL
             ------------------------------------- */
            * {
                font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
                font-size: 100%;
                line-height: 2.0em;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                text-align: left;
            }

            img {
                max-width: 600px;
                width: 100%;
            }

            body {
                -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
                height: 100%;
                -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
                width: 100% !important;
            }

            /* -------------------------------------
             ELEMENTS
             ------------------------------------- */
            a {
                color: #348eda;
            }

            .btn-primary {
                margin-bottom: 10px;
                width: auto !important;
            }

            .btn-primary td {
                background-color: #348eda;
                border-radius: 25px;
                font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
                font-size: 14px;
                text-align: center;
                vertical-align: top;
            }

            .btn-primary td a {
                background-color: #348eda;
                border: solid 1px #348eda;
                border-radius: 25px;
                border-width: 10px 20px;
                display: inline-block;
                color: #ffffff;
                cursor: pointer;
                font-weight: bold;
                line-height: 2;
                text-decoration: none;
            }

            .last {
                margin-bottom: 0;
            }

            .first {
                margin-top: 0;
            }

            .padding {
                padding: 10px 0;
            }

            /* -------------------------------------
             BODY
             ------------------------------------- */
            table.body-wrap {
                padding: 20px;
                width: 100%;
            }

            table.body-wrap .container {
                border: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
            }

            /* -------------------------------------
             FOOTER
             ------------------------------------- */
            table.footer-wrap {
                clear: both !important;
                width: 100%;
            }

            .footer-wrap .container p {
                color: #666666;
                font-size: 12px;
            }

            table.footer-wrap a {
                color: #999999;
            }

            /* -------------------------------------
             TYPOGRAPHY
             ------------------------------------- */
            h1, h2, h3 {
                color: #111111;
                font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
                font-weight: 200;
                line-height: 1.2em;
                margin: 40px 0 10px;
            }

            h1 {
                font-size: 36px;
            }
            h2 {
                font-size: 28px;
            }
            h3 {
                font-size: 22px;
            }

            p, ul, ol {
                font-size: 14px;
                font-weight: normal;
                margin: 0; 
                padding: 0;
                margin-bottom: 10px;
                float: none;
                text-align: left;
            }

            ul li, ol li {
                margin-left: 5px;
                list-style-position: inside;
            }

            /* ---------------------------------------------------
             RESPONSIVENESS
             ------------------------------------------------------ */

            /* Set a max-width, and make it display as block so it will automatically stretch to that width, but will also shrink down on a phone or something */
            .container {
                clear: both !important;
                display: block !important;
                Margin: 0 auto !important;
                max-width: 600px !important;
            }

            /* Set the padding on the td rather than the div for Outlook compatibility */
            .body-wrap .container {
                padding: 20px;
            }

            /* This should also be a block element, so that it will fill 100% of the .container */
            .content {
                display: block;
                margin: 0 auto;
                max-width: 600px;
            }

            /* Let's make sure tables in the content area are 100% wide */
            .content table {
                width: 100%;
            }

        </style>
    </head>

    <body bgcolor="#f6f6f6">

        <!-- body -->
        <table width="100%" class="body-wrap" bgcolor="#f6f6f6" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td class="container" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><!-- content -->
                <div class="content">
                    <table width="100%" style="width: 100%; text-align: left;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                        <tr style="width: 100%; text-align: left;" >
                            <td align="left" style="width: 100%; text-align: left;" >

                                Hi John Doe,

                            <p style="text-align: left; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; float: none; display: block;">
                                You have been invited to attend a meeting.
                            </p>
                            <h4>Topic</h4>
                            <p style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0; margin:0; text-align:left;" >A Samle Meeting!</p>

                            <h4>Summmary</h4>
                            <p style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0; margin:0; text-align:left;" >
                                A sample meeting to prove the concept work andthen take it form there
                            </p>


                                <h4>Location</h4>
                                <p>
                                    123 Example Street New york, NY
                                </p>


                            <h4>Time</h4>
                            <p>
                                From: February 7, 2016, 2:28 am GMT-0500  <br />
                                To: February 9, 2016, 3:50 pm GMT-0500
                            </p>
                            <h4>Next Steps</h4>
                            <p>
                                You may view more information on the meeting by clicking the link below
                            </p><!-- button -->
                            <table class="btn-primary" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                                <tr>
                                    <td><a href="http://www.example.com">View Meeting</a></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table><!-- /button -->
                            <p>
                                Please adjust your meeting schedule infomration there.
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                Thanks,
                            </p>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div><!-- /content --></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <!-- /body -->

        <!-- footer -->
        <table class="footer-wrap">
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td class="container"><!-- content -->
                <div class="content">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div><!-- /content --></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <!-- /footer -->

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested your email in latest Thunderbird and paragraphs seem to be where they should be.

You may be however referring to the 20px padding set on the "container" with white background. Removing the padding will make the text stick to the left side of white space.

Since both Gmail and Yahoo ignore CSS in HEAD you do not see the padding there.

Personally I would advice against removing the padding for esthetic reason.

[Preview in Thunderbird 38.5.1 (Windows)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WblCT.png)

Answer (score 0):

The problem quite stupid actually. Apparently the spaces in the html were causing the problem.So I changed

```
<p style="text-align: left; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; float: none; display: block;">
                                You have been invited to attend a meeting.
                            </p>
```

To

```
<p style="text-align: left; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; float: none; display: block;">You have been invited to attend a meeting</p>
```

With no space and problem fixed